# Does the human brain use beam search for text generation?

Tags: natural-language-processing, brain

As far as I understand, [beam search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLWuzLLSIgw) is the most widely used algorithm for text generation in NLP. So I was wondering: does the human brain also use beam search for text generation? If not, then what?

Comment: i dont think neuroscience is far enough to the point it can answer that....
beamsearch is an effective and memory constrained method of approximating the sequence that maximizes the joint probability

Comment: I think text generation uses for more different approaches than just this one algorithm. There is a lot of NLP happening which does not involve neural networks/deep learning approaches.

Comment: @OliverMason for example ... ?

Comment: Any work in text generation in the past 60 years.

Comment: @OliverMason would you mind being more specific? For example, any state of the art method which does not use beam search? Some concrete references/links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I thought the answer might be no.

[image]

In this 2020 ICLR paper: [The Curious Case of Neural Text Degeneration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09751), researchers found that beam search text is less surprising compared to human natural language. And they proposed a nucleus sampling method which generates more human like text.